# HTML canvas fillrect uses wrong color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to implement a simple snake game with using html canvas.
I use this code to make snake move (make tail white and draw new rectangle for head, top, left, wid and hid I compute before):

```
        if (currentSnake.length == 45) {
            var tail = currentSnake.shift();
            ctx.fillStyle="white";
            ctx.fillRect(tail.left, tail.top, tail.wid, tail.hid);
        }
        currentSnake.push({top: top, left: left,wid: wid, hid: hid});

        ctx.fillStyle=coef[2];
        ctx.fillRect(left, top, wid, hid);
```

where coef[2] is some color I've defined earlier.
Everything is ok, but snake's tail becomes not white (some type of mix of colors between coef[2] and white).
How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: You try to overwrite the parts that where blue before with white?

Comment: @CodeiSir, yes, I want to make them 'completely' white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if (currentSnake.length == 45) {
    var tail = currentSnake.shift();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(Math.floor(tail.left), Math.floor(tail.top), 
        Math.ceil(tail.wid), Math.ceil(tail.hid));
}
```

This should solve the problem of the smooth edges. But it's not perfect.

The best solution would to clear the canvas completely in white every time and redraw all body parts of your snake.

Comment: The last paragraph is the correct answer. The code only really works for rectangles and even then you should use `clearRect` instead (uses transparent instead of white). Also, this can break if a clip is set.

Comment: you don't need `clearRect` if you do 'fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)' in white

Comment: You do if your canvas is not on a white background. Either jsFiddle has been updated or my switch to Firefox effected the change but the results window is light gray instead of white now. This snake will leave a trail in that case.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't understand?

Comment: A canvas is transparent by default, not white. Try displaying a canvas over a non-white element. Giving a CSS gradient background to the document body will demonstrate the difference nicely.

Comment: Yes, but he wants it to be white?!

Comment: I don't think he does... he tries to erase it but he doesn't know about `clearRect`, and you've got a great opportunity to tell him.

Comment: No there is no reason I would assume he trys to use a transparent canvas and wants to clear parts of it with transparent color. I could assume a lot of things.. Note that I asked him if he wants to overwrite it with white

Comment: He may not care about the difference now but he certainly will if he ever tries to use a non-white background in the future. Are you going to intentionally make your answer less useful for the unfortunate folk who have to deal with canvases that are not over a plain white background by deliberately not including a paragraph I've basically served you on a golden plate?

Comment: I would rather assume he already made his canvas white at the beginning of the game

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you're doing here, you're trying to draw OVER old parts in order to "remove" the past positions?

This seems to pretty much be the definition of an [X Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Clear the old frame, draw the new one. That's how you do this sort of thing.